# 12 V split charge system, full circuit specs

Tags: electrical, battery, wiring, relay

I'm working on a 12 V split charge system in a vehicle and I'm confused about which components to choose.

**Here's my current setup**

- Alternator (BOSCH A0165) : 150 Amps
- Relay (NAGARES RDT/3-12) : 100 - 180 Amps
- Wiring between the batteries (stranded copper) : 4m (13 feet), 10mm² (7 AWG)
- In-line fuse : 40 Amps (not sure here)
- Auxiliary battery (UPOWER UP-SP160 AGM) : these specs I don't understand... (see image below or keep reading)

**Battery manual gives several capacity values**

- C1 (9.60V) : 85 Ah
- C5 (10.20V) : 115 Ah
- C10 (10.80V) : 130 Ah
- C100 (10.80V) : 160 Ah
- Cr (10.5V) : 260 min

**And also these cryptic sentences**

- Charge with constant current : Current limit: 10 - 20 % from C10 capacity rate
- Charge with constant voltage : Voltage limit: 14.1 - 15.0 V per block

**In a nutshell**

- How do I know how much current can the battery realistically draw when the relay turns on?
- Is my wiring undersized? I guess I need to know the current draw...

*Any help greatly appreciated.*

[image: auxiliary battery specs]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The only thing which is popping to me is the wire gauge is extremely small. I'd highly suggest you up that to at least a 2AWG size. With wiring, you cannot go too big with the wire. Obviously, there's a ludicrous size, but something between a 1-0 and 2AWG is going to be a lot better than the 7AWG. Also, the battery doesn't draw power. It provides power unless it has none to provide.

Comment: Thx @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 , may I ask why 2 AWG ? Are there any formulas/charts about how to pick a wire gauge according to the amount of current it can handle ? 
Also, if not determined by the battery, any ideas on how both the alternator and the relay "decide" on the amount of charging current to flow through the circuit ?
Cheers.

Comment: Most (if not all) modern alternators have regulators which tells the alternator how much juice to output up to their rated output (usually rated in Amps). As far as the wiring AWG, that is just my suggestion and is probably overkill. It just seems to me 7AWG is quite small for what I'm assuming the draw will or could be. If you do a Google search, you can find AWG guidance based on voltage and amperage loads required. Most wire manufacturers will have guidance on their sites.

Comment: Dual battery use in recreational vehicles;  https://camperfaqs.com/how-to-charge-rv-batteries#:~:text=An%20RV's%20battery%20is%20charged,vehicles%20alternator%2C%20or%20solar%20power.